# Пустая страница в CefSharp после нажатия на кнопку на странице

Tags: c#, cefsharp

написал немного кода, который открывает страницу по ссылке. Но столкнулся с проблемой, суть которой в том, что после нажатия на кнопку "Далее" на открытой странице должна открыться другая страница, но она по какой-то причине пустая. Мне кажется, что дело в запросах, но у меня не получается решить данную проблему. Также я видел подобный вопрос, но там было сказано, что ошибки в скриптах страницы, но решения вопроса там не было. Если кто-то знает как решить эту проблему помогите, пожалуйста.

```
private async void Clicker(ChromiumWebBrowser CWBrowser)
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    CWBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("(function(){ document.getElementsByClassName('contents-3NembX')[0].click(); })();");
}
```

Comment: `await` забыли, ну а так, я вам очень сильно советую научиться парсить сайты без использования браузеров...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо за то, что обратили внимание на мой вопрос. Но я не понимаю куда ещё необходимо написать `await` , если я напишу `await` на 4 строчке, то компилятор выдаст ошибку "Ожидание void невозможно". Возможно вы имели ввиду какую-то конструкцию?

Comment: Хм, странное тогда именование у авторов Cef. Обычно методы с припиской `...Async` означают то, что это асинхронная `Task`, задача, которая запускается через `await` и ожидается, тут это явно не так. Вообще, я на вашем месте сделал что-то [вроде этого (я про код)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65482067/6808809), где есть и ожидание загрузки страницы, и полноценный `await`. Но а так, все еще про отказа от браузера подумайте, очень часто он просто не нужен.